# Any ways to ignore files without using .gitignore

Tags: git

I would like to ignore `Test2.java` file in my directory.

I don't want to update `.gitignore` since I don't want to leave any evidence that `Test2.java` file exist in my remote repository.

Is there anyways to "untrack" one of my file without using git `.gitignore` ?

While doing my research, I've tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged` but it gave me the following error.

```
fatal: Unable to mark file src/com/gmail/.../.../Test2.java
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This file is still untracked. It will not be commited unless you stage it using git add. If you don't do that, it won't be uploaded and you won't have to add it to .gitignore either.

Comment: @ProudOne You are right, but many times, I use `git add -A` before commits which adds this file to my repository. Bad habit but that is what I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ignore it via the [`.git/info/exclude` file in your repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description). This file is just like `.gitignore` but it isn't tracked and therefore isn't shared among other copies of the repository.

Comment: It worked but why haven't `git update-index --assume-unchanged` worked? Isn't it basically the same thing?

Comment: Because that command operates on the index. Untracked files, by definition, aren't in the index.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is it going to be the same if I add my file using `git add` and `git update-index --assume-unchanged`?

Comment: '.gitignore' is for untracked files (which is your case). `assume-unchanged` is to improve performance on big files that has not changed and will not. `skip-worktree` is for files that has changed but you don't want to commit (and see when doing a `status`)

Comment: @gidonyou, Philippe is correct. Why would you want to add this file to the index and then use assume unchanged when you've got a good solution in the `.git/info/exclude` file?